# Ef Core - Adding unique index

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-core

I've added

```
 builder.Entity<SiteInformation>().HasIndex(i => i.Url).IsUnique();
```

to my application context`s`OnModelCreating` method, but for some reason an index isn't added to the database. I've ran the migrations from scratch but still no luck.

The column is an `nvarchar(max)` which is `required`.

I've also thrown an exception in the `OnModelCreating` method to check it's been called.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot do** that.Your column on which (`Url`) you want to define a `unique constraint` must be less then or equal to `900 bytes`.If you want to create unique constraint on the `Url`, You have to set it as `VARCHAR(900)` or `NVARCHAR(450)`.This is not an issue on `EF core`.That is restriction on `SQL server`.

Let's say if you're going to create a table on `MSSQL SERVER` as shown below :

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable 
(ID INT, MyEmail NVARCHAR(1000) CONSTRAINT Unique_Constarin_Email UNIQUE (MyEmail))
GO
```

Then it gives `warning` as shown below :

> Warning! The maximum key length is 900 bytes. The index
>   'Unique_Constarin_Email' has maximum length of 2000 bytes. For some
>   combination of large values, the insert/update operation will fail.

Comment: I shouldn't have known that :-( Side note would be great to have EF report a warning.

Comment: Yep..that is true.But unfortunately not yet..Hope they'll do that in the future :)